# Como reiniciar proceso Scanner.exe cuando este no consuma CPU?

Tags: python

Buen dia,

Tengo un problema con un proceso que se llama Scanner.exe el cual no hace su funcion cuando este no consume CPU... he notado que cuando este proceso consume CPU si funciona bien pero tiempo despues deja de consumir CPU y es cuando este ya no hace su funcion y tengo que cerrar y volver a abrir este proceso.

Me gustaria que me pudieran apoyar a encontrar una solucion para cuando este ya no consuma CPU se reinicio dicho proceso.

Esta es una imagen del proceso funcionando bien y consumiendo CPU
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es una imagen del proceso no consume CPU y ya no hace su funcion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacerlo con Python pero en ocaciones si funciona y en otras veces no.. asi como tambien este debe de permanecer siempre revisando que el proceso no se detenga.

```html
import psutil
import time

proceso = 'Scanner.exe'

while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        for process in psutil.process_iter():
                if process.name() == proceso:
                        cpu = process.cpu_percent()
                        if cpu == 0.0:
                                process.kill()
                                #time.sleep(3)
                        else:
                                print("El proceso sigue corriendo")
                else:
                        print("El proceso no existe")
```

Por alguna razon cuando el proceso no consume CPU primero me paracen machas veces mi mensaje "El proceso sigue corriendo" y despues hace la funcion de cerrar el proceso Scanner.exe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intentaste poner tu código en un bucle infinito ?

Comment: si pero llega a un punto donde el bucle consume demaciada memoria

Comment: puedes intentar ejecutar la revisión cada cierto tiempo, por ejemplo: con un time.sleep(20), revisa una sola vez cada 20 segundos, de esa manera no consumirá tanta memoria